# ARM Template create and publish Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation

My scenario:

I have three runbooks (A, B and C) hosted in github (AUri, BUri, CUri). I'm working on ARM template to create automation account, credential, the three runbooks and then create a job using one of them (runbook C).

Runbook C is the main one and A and B are being called inside C.

The problem is that for A and B to be called from C they need to be published first.

**Is there a way to publish them directly via my current ARM template?**

A workaround will be to squeeze all my code in runbook C but I prefer to keep them separate.

The code so far:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
   .......
  },
  "variables": {
   ........
  },
  "resources": [
    {
   "name": "[parameters('accountName')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
  "type": "Microsoft.Automation/AutomationAccounts",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "properties": {
    "sku": {
      "name": "Basic"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]"
      ],
      "location": "westeurope",
      "name": "[variables('A')]",
      "properties": {
        "runbookType": "Script",
        "logProgress": "false",
        "logVerbose": "false",
        "description": "[variables('runbookDescription')]",
        "publishContentLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('AUri')]",
          "version": "1.0.0.0"
        }
      },
      "type": "runbooks"
    },

    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]"
      ],
      "location": "westeurope",
      "name": "[variables('B')]",
      "properties": {
        "runbookType": "Script",
        "logProgress": "false",
        "logVerbose": "false",
        "description": "[variables('runbookDescription')]",
        "publishContentLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('BUri')]",
          "version": "1.0.0.0"
        }
      },
      "type": "runbooks"
    },

    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]"
      ],
      "location": "westeurope",
      "name": "[variables('C')]",
      "properties": {
        "runbookType": "Script",
        "logProgress": "false",
        "logVerbose": "false",
        "description": "[variables('runbookDescription')]",
        "publishContentLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('CUri')]",
          "version": "1.0.0.0"
        }
      },
      "type": "runbooks"
    },

    {
      "name": "[parameters('credentialName')]",
      "type": "credentials",
      "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": { },
      "properties": {
        "userName": "[parameters('userName')]",
        "password": "[parameters('password')]"
      }
    }
    //optional code that runs the runbook created, yo need unique Guid value for "name" key
    ,
    {
      "name": "Unique GUID Here",
      "type": "jobs",
      "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'), '/credentials/', parameters('credentialName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'), '/runbooks/',variables('A'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'), '/runbooks/',variables('B'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'), '/runbooks/',variables('C'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "key": "value"
      },
      "properties": {
        "runbook": {
          "name": "[variables('C')]"
        }
      }
    } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are already publishing the runbooks correctly via the template, since you are providing a `publishContentLink`. Your issue is most likely that you are not marking runbook C as dependent on runbook A and B, so C may be being published before A and B, and currently in Azure Automation, whenever a runbook is published, any child runbooks it depends on must be published first at least once.

The solution is to make C runbook's dependsOn field look like:

`"dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'), '/runbooks/', variables('B'))]",
 "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'), '/runbooks/', variables('A'))]"
]`

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I've added dependency in the job that's using runbook C to A and B but not added these in Runbook C itself as you pointed out. Also added `"state": "Published"` to each runbook. Is there an extensive documentation regarding creating a schedule for example?

Comment: For schedule, please see https://github.com/azureautomation/automation-packs/tree/master/000-base-automation-resource-templates/deploy-schedule

Comment: Thanks @Joe, can I pass @{Param1 = value1, etc..} from my ARM template?

Comment: Are you trying to set the parameter values that are passed to the job when the schedule starts the job? If so, yes that can be done, see https://github.com/azureautomation/automation-packs/blob/master/102-sample-automation-setup/azuredeploy.json

Comment: @Joe RE: "any child runbooks it depends on must be published first **at least once**" If the child runbook is changed and re-published, does the parent need to be re-published as well for those subsequent child runbook changes to be picked up on the next Job execution? (And is this behavior different depending on the type of runbook: ie Native vs WF)

Comment: Nope, the parent runbook would not need to be republished, as long as the child runbook had been published at least once before the parent runbook was published. It's only a first time thing.

Comment: @Joe Does that mean a broken parent (published before the child) should simply start working once the child is published? The behavior I'm seeing right now is that the parent has to be republished.

Comment: ie: using RM cmdlets, import parent, then child, both with -published, and both no errors. run parent job: runtime error; can't find cmdlet. edit w/ no changes, try test pane, runs fine. revert, start job again, still broken. edit again, republish parent, start job.. now runs fine.

Comment: "Does that mean a broken parent (published before the child) should simply start working once the child is published?" - No, all child runbooks must be published at least once before their parent runbooks are published. If you publish a parent runbook before a child runbook, you need to publish the child runbook, and then republish the parent runbook.